# Put Space Between 2 Digits in Php?

Tags: php, string

I either get a one digit or a two digit number from my database like 52,8,4,99 etc. What i want to do now is to display the number with a space in between if the number is two digit like "5 2". How do i do this?

Comment: You have to enforce an extra condition to satisfy "*if the number is two digit*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
echo join(' ', str_split($number));
```